# Buildozer fails when deploying Kivy App on Andoird

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer, ubuntu-20.04

I'm new at building Apps in Kivy and I'm having trouble building an .apk for android in buildozer on Ubuntu 20.04

As far as I can tell, I followed all the instructions to setup buildozer and its dependencies:

1. git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer.git to get buildozer
2. Installed python3.8 : sudo apt-get install python3.8
3. Installed setup-tools for python3: sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
4. cd Buildzer & sudo python setup.py install
5. buildozer init in my folder where I have a .py & .kv file ( described below ).
6. Install Buildozer dependencies:
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk python3-pip autoconf libtool pkg-config zlib1g-dev
   libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libtinfo5 cmake libffi-dev libssl-dev
   pip3 install --user --upgrade Cython==0.29.19 virtualenv
7. Added "export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/" in my .bashrc file
8. Deploy my code on my android phone : buildozer android debug deploy run

The code itslef in the .py file is just:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import vibrator

#presentation = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class AndroidApp(Widget):
    def vibrate(self):
        vibrator.vibrate()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AndroidApp()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()


.kv file:
#:import utils kivy.utils
<AndroidApp>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        size: root.width, root.height
        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

            rows: 1
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text:"Android app"
            Button:
                text: "Vibrate"
                on_press:
                    root.vibrate()
```

The error I get is the following:
[buildozer error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnLFw.png)

It seems it cant find Cyhton although I installed it as part of the buildozer dependencies.
Can anyone explain what this error even means? :) Im a bit overwhelmed with this buildozer setup ( although they say its the easiest option for beginners ).

As a note, the build process also threw me this warning, complaining about "python recipe found".
[python recipe warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoJ9b.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Alex

Comment: I think the problem may actually be with `ssl`. Tr installing it with `pip install ssl`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson: thanks for the hint. that was the problem